# For every wordpress page edit window is blank when I go to edit a page

Tags: wordpress

For every wordpress page edit window is blank when I go to edit a page. It was working okay earlier today, and Ive tried on multiple browsers and same problem on each (using Wordpress 3.3.1).

When I first click on edit the text is displayed in the edit window momentarily before disappearing.

EDIT:Created .htaccess file containing the following

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

but seeing no errors coming up

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour on all browsers ?

Comment: Yes, ive tried on Firefox and Chrome so far.

Comment: I'm not sure that Wordpress is the problem, Did you try with another computer ?

Comment: Yes I have, the problem is only within Wordpress Dasboard this is certainly a wordpress problem

Comment: You can try reinstalling wordpress

Comment: Well thats another thing, I tried upgrading to 3.4 but it complained about my username,password even though I can connecto the site using ftp with the exact same username and password.

Comment: turn on debug and watch for errors: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug If that doesn't give errors turn errors on in htaccess http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/14/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/

Comment: I tried turning on debugging in wp_config.php that and it shows error when you view the wordpress site itself in a browser, but it didnt show anything extra when just trying to edit pages within the site.

Comment: But where is .htaccess ?

Comment: root folder of your website, if not, you have to create one into your wordpress root folder

Comment: Thx, yes I worked it out but has seem to have no effect,

Comment: in the end I had to recreate the site from scratch